# How to pass data to php file from C# app and receiver response?

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I have a C# application and I have a database on my server which doesn't allow remote mysql connections
and I need to write and read data from this database with my app
for now I wrote this code with php to store data in the database using $_GET

```
require_once('config.php');

$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$identity = $_GET['id'];
if ($phone != Null && $pass != Null && $identity != Null )
{
$exist = " SELECT * FROM channels WHERE phone = '$phone' " ;
$q = mysql_query($exist);
if (mysql_num_rows($q) != Null)
{
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM channels WHERE phone = '$phone' ");
echo 'number exist';
}
else
{
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO channels(phone,password,identity) VALUES('$phone','$pass','$identity')");
echo 'number added';
}
}
else
{
echo 'Some data is missing';
}
```

now I need to know
1- how to call this file from my app and pass data to it? what is the code to do this?
2- how to receive results from the php file ( I need both php code and c# code )like if the number is existing or added and how many numbers added to the database and so on?
3- if there are many copies from my app with many clients which call the same file in the same time, will this affect the performance of the php file? and if yes how to solve this? how to call the same file 100 times in the same time without effecting the performance?
and forgive me for my poor Englis.
thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: put you php script on a web server. Access from c# using WebRequest client or HttpClient. About concurrent access, it depends on the scalability and physical resource strenght of the webserver you are using.

Comment: A hint to help you find information. The php program is called a "web service" .

Comment: @elf yes I know, this php code will be a file on the server, I'll do some research about WebRequest client and HttpClient.. thank you